# compiler error expected nested-name specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, gcc4.6

I am the OP for the question: [Extending a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999263/extending-a-class) in which I received an excellent answer.  However, as I try to compile the code (reworked slightly for my project) I received the following message (line no. changed to reflect following sample code):

```
except.h: | 09 | expected nested-name-specifier before ‘handler_t1’
```

along with many more which seem to stem from this line.  I am brand new to C++, and my research into the answer (and the forthcoming problem) has yielded this fact: Microsoft's compiler seems to accept the code, but standards compliant ones do not.

The code as I currently have it is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
namespace except
{
  // several other classes and functions which compile and work already
  // (tested and verified) have been snipped out. Entire code is over
  // 1000 lines.

  class Error_Handler
  {
    public:
      using handler_t1 = bool (*)(except::Logic const&);
      std::vector<handler_t1> logic_handlers;

      // a lot more removed because the error has already happened ...
  }
}
```

A read through of the code in the linked question indicates to me (with my limited knowledge) that it should all work.

My question therefore is:  What do I need to change in this declaration/definition to enable this to compile with gcc (4.6.3 64 bit linux compiling with -std=C++0x)?

Comment: I don't know much about C++11 but does this help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCC 4.6.3 doesn't support C++11 type aliases: `using handler_t1 = bool (*)(except::Logic const&);`. Non-template type aliases are equivalent to typedefs: `typedef bool (*handler_t1)(except::Logic const&);`. Replace them and see if that helps.

Or even better, upgrade to a more recent compiler version. I believe the regular responders here tend to write to the portion of the language compiled by GCC 4.8.

EDIT: The only other iffy feature I see in that answer is range-based-for, which I believe GCC added support for in 4.6. You should be OK after replacing the type aliases with typedefs.

Comment: I found the relevant standard quote. `7.1.3.2 A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains to that typedef-name. It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.`. Also, http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html. You'll see a big red no next to `template alises`.

Comment: @remyabel Excellent reference.  Being new to C++ I had no idea that different compilers required different syntax,  or offered different feature sets.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem and it solved by just upgrading go G++ 4.8 in my Ubuntu.

I assume that you already have a former version of gcc, the easiest way could be adding PPA to your repositories and Update and upgrade you can have the latest version with no worries:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
>
> sudo apt-get update

this will add the new PPA to the other sources.

Then unistall the alternative:

> sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
>
> sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++

then:

> sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
>
> sudo apt-get install g++-4.8

and as the alternative packages install :

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 20
>
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 20
>
> sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
>
> sudo update-alternatives --config g++

at the end:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade -y
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Hope this changes the --version ;)

Answer (score 1):

With g++ before version 6 you need the option `--std=c++11` to be able to use the `using` directive.

Comment: Especially since I was working with a version higher than 4.8, but lower than 6